# Is Core data always necessary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have developed about ten apps for iOS. And I haven't needed to use Core Data! All my apps are consistently based on receiving data from servers. Most of the apps have large feed lists, similar to Facebook and Instagram.

However CoreData is a large topic in iOS development, and I'm thinking maybe I'm missing something? There is no data I need to save, and if I do its a large file like an image or a audio file, I usually save it to the disk, because I believe Core Data is not suitable for large files.

In apps like Facebook or Instagram, what need is there for Core Data?

Comment: So you download your feed content, presumably paginated, and the user can scroll through it. You have it all loaded into memory at the same time? How do you deal with the long list of scrollable content? Core Data isn't the only way obviously, but it can help.

Comment: **No** framework is always necessary except probably UIKit.

Comment: @Wain for a large feed i just use paging, i would not want to keep any data because the feed is refreshing constantly for view counts, comments and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Core Data is interesting when you have a lot of objects with relationships and if you don't want to manipulate SQLite requests.

There are no best and miracle way to store data, it just depends on your needs.

If you just manipulate data coming from a webservice and don't want to store it for caching them (and access it offline) you can just use objects created right after your parsing.

Maybe if you want to store some preferences data (which are no need to be secure) you can use [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

If you just want to store your graph of Data (maybe some custom objects linked to another and stored on NSArray or NSDictionary) you can implements [NSKeyedArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with [NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/protocols/nscoding_protocol/reference/reference.html) protocol.

This is a great way to easily store your data.

Please go reed this great article written by [Matt Thompson](https://github.com/mattt) called [NSCoding / NSKeyed​Archiver](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/).

He explains everything way better than I do and make comparaison with Core Data.

Hope I helped you !